# Make the specific record to the top and the subsequent rows should be sorted based on the nearest number of the top record

Tags: mysql

I have a list of birthday celebrants, and I want to display this according to what my title says, for instance:

```
+-------------------------------------+------------+
| parties_name                        | birthday   |
+-------------------------------------+------------+
| John Doe Lee                        | 2016-02-15 |
| Lee Doe John                        | 2016-02-17 |
| Jane Doe Lee                        | 2016-02-18 |
| Spongebob Squarepants               | 2016-02-19 |
| Sandy Cheeks                        | 2016-02-01 |
| Squidward Tentacles                 | 2016-02-02 |
| Patrick Starfish                    | 2016-02-03 |
+-------------------------------------+------------+
```

Assuming that the person at the top of the record is the current birthday celebrant, while the underlying persons are the next celebrants, and the last rows are the previous celebrants. Any suggestions without using UNION or UNION ALL? Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution could be:

```
SELECT parties_name, birthday
    FROM birthdays
    WHERE birthday >= UTC_DATE
    ORDER BY birthday ASC

UNION

SELECT parties_name, birthday
    FROM birthdays
    WHERE birthday < UTC_DATE
    ORDER BY birthday ASC
```

**UPDATE:** And we can execute this in 1 query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Birthdays
  ORDER BY CASE WHEN Birthday >= UTC_DATE THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC
```

Please check the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9948/12)

Comment: Is there any other solution without using UNION?For me, it looks redundant, but anyway thanks for answering @Kael. If there's no other possible solution, I'll use your suggestion instead :)

Comment: It works perfectly as expected! Thank you very much ^_^

Comment: No problem @Chisskarzz ^_^